# Excel Apply Autofilter and Customfilter using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file in which the worksheet handle variable name is `wks_yella`. I am attempting to apply autofilter using `auto_filter.add_filter_column` and `openpyxl.worksheet.filters.CustomFilterValueDescriptor`.
The filters using `auto_filter` is taking effect but `openpyxl.worksheet.filters.CustomFilterValueDescriptor` isn't.

This is the code chunk

```
# Apply filters on both Column B (2nd column) and Column E (5th column)
wks_yella.auto_filter.ref = f'A1:T{wks_yella.max_row}'  # Update the range for all columns

wks_yella.auto_filter.add_filter_column(1, vals=saka_filter, blank=True)
wks_yella.auto_filter.add_filter_column(4, vals=gothram_filter, blank=True)

regex_pattern = r'.*199[3-6].*'
custom_filter = openpyxl.worksheet.filters.CustomFilterValueDescriptor(pattern=regex_pattern)
wks_yella.column_dimensions['G'].filter = custom_filter
```

Can I get some help to resolve the issue.

Comment: there is insufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: also, can you clarify, are you trying to [1] use python create the filter **in excel** or [2] create a filter from excel as an output in **python** ?

Comment: You haven't clarified what it is you are attempting to achieve or what data you are working with.

Comment: **I have an excel file in which the worksheet handle variable name is `wks_yella`. I am attempting to apply autofilter **, Using `python`. The excel file has strings (`str()`) in `col G` and I want apply `filter()` where the cell values contain string of the pattern `r'.*199[3-6].*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of a workaround.

In the target Excel File, I have used `Condtional Formatting` Option to highlight the `column G` when cell values contain the values like 1993,1994, 1995 and 1996.
Under the `Contional Formatting` I selected `=>Use a formula to determine which cells to highlight` in the `Format Values where this formula is true` textbox placed this formula `=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1993", G1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1994", G1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1995", G1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1996", G1)))`, then set the cell format fill and text fonts.

And the requirements were highlighted. Then I have simply selected the filters by font.

Comment: Would there be something in my conduct which is inappropriate, you would need to [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) it so that a moderator can investigate. But in this case, you are simply confused. It would have been better if you adjusted your expectations and learned how the site operates before making unfounded accusations. The help center has a few more pages on that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior